# Img being rendered with an anchor when it shouldn't

Tags: css, email, outlook

I have an issue that I've spent hours trying to find the cause but haven't been successful.

So the customer is having issues rendering a product image, and it is a specific product only and to make matters even more puzzled is that they have two Outlook emails and only on one inbox does this issues arise.

I've checked my code, database and asked the customer to change some settings in their email client and there's no reason why that image element is inserting an anchor when it shouldn't.

Here's the email source code:

```
<td align="left"><img src="<a href="https://customerSite/Files/Images/Products/Equipment">https://customerSite/Files/Images/Products/E      
quipment</a> Images/10108.jpg" width="105" class="flexibleImage" style="height: 
        auto !important;max-width: 100% !important;display: block;" alt="10108" 
    />image=/Files/Images/Products/Equipment Images/10108.jpg" width="105" 
    class="flexibleImage" style="height: auto !important;max-width: 100% 
    !important;display: block;" alt="Some Product" />;
</td>
```

And here's a product image which doesn't have an anchor in the middle:

```
<td align="left">
    <img src="https://customerSite/Files/Images/Products/Equipment Images/10662.jpg" width="105" 
    class="flexibleImage" style="height: auto !important;max-width: 100% !important;display: block;" 
    alt="10662">
</td>
```

I'm asking here to see if anyone has come up with this problem and if they found a solution after running out of possibilities.

Comment: Check for this class .flexibleImage. It might have pointer properties or something

Comment: That class only has height, width, max-width and margin properties

Comment: Okay and did you ask in which version of outlook client he is facing the problem

Comment: Going to ask him, will answer back when I have the answer.

Comment: They are using Microsoft Outlook 2016 (16.0.5017.1000). I don't know what to look for between versions. Does it help?

Comment: Any help with this?

Comment: It really seems strange. Would revert to you if I found something helpful

Comment: Thanks. It has been a wild goose chase trying to fix this issue.

Comment: did you resolve the issue ?